# How to highlight a PrimeFaces textbox with red color border on required validation error?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces textbox with autocomplete functionality. For required field validation error i have to show the error message and highlight the textbox with red color border. I have showed the error message with `<h:message>` how to highlight the textbox with red color border.

My textbox is mentioned below.

```
<p:focus context="accountNo">
                             <p:autoComplete id="accountNo" value="#{orderController.accountNo}"
                                  completeMethod="#{orderController.getAccountAutoComplete}"
                                  forceSelection="true"  styleClass="ui-inputfield" requiredMessage="Account number is required"  required="true"/>
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h:message for="accountNo"  style="color:red" />

                              </p:focus>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<p:message>` with `for` attribute set to id of textbox.

For example:

```
<p:inputText id="id" value="#{bean.idd}"     />
<p:message for="id" display="icon" />
```

Comment: I have showed the message. I want the textbox to be highlighted with red color border.

Comment: Ok, with this primefaces component that I've showed you, you will get that higlight

Comment: but with this i am getting highlight for error message not for the textbox. Thanks for the response

Comment: For me inputtext component is also highlighted

Comment: Now I've tried in my code. This doesn't work for h:inputText. I suppose that you use h:inputText. I suggest primefaces component p:inputText

Comment: I have used P:autocomplete miro, u can see my code above i updated it in my question.